# VHDL program to count upto 10 in 4 bit up counter....?

Tags: vhdl

```
     library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all; 

entity counter is 
  port(CLK, CLR : in  std_logic; 
       output : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)); 
end counter; 
architecture archi of counter is 
  signal tmp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
  begin 
    process (CLK, CLR)
     variable i: integer:=0;
        begin

           if (CLR='1') then
                tmp <= "0000";
           elsif (clk = '1') then
                for i in 0 to 6 loop
                    tmp <= tmp + 1;
                end loop;
            end if;
```

to count upto 7 i have done for i in 0 to 10. it is not showing any error but it counts from 0000 to 1111

```
    end process;
     output <= tmp;

end architecture;
```

could you please suggest how to do it....sorry for wrong grammar in english

Comment: For loops don't work the way you think they do.  Rewrite your code and remove the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

### Needs to operate off one clock edge

Because your `counter` `port` has `clk` in it, we can assume you want the counter to count synchronous to the clock.

You're operating off of both clock edges

```
         elsif (clk = '1') then
```

should be something like

```
         elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
```

or

```
         elsif rising_edge(clk) then
```

These examples use the rising edge of clk.  You can't synthesize something that uses both clock edges under the IEEE-1076.6 IEEE Standard for VHDL Register
Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis.  It's not a recognized clocking method.

### Making a modulo 10 counter

Under the assumption you want the counter to go from 0 to 9 and rollover this

```
            for i in 0 to 6 loop
                tmp <= tmp + 1;
            end loop;
```

Should be something like

```
            if tmp = "1001" then         # binary 9
                tmp <= (others => '0');  # equivalent to "0000"
            else
                tmp <= tmp + 1;
            end if;
```

And this emulates a synchronous load that takes priority over increment driven by an external 'state' recognizer.  With an asynchronous clear it would emulate an 74163 4 bit counter with an external 4 input gate recognizing "1001" and producing a synchronous parallel load signal loading "0000".

### What's wrong with the loop statement

The loop process as shown would result in a single increment and resulting counter rollover at `"1111"` like you describe.  You could remove the `for ... loop` and `end loop;` statements and it would behave identically.  There's only one schedule future update for a signal for each driver, and a process only has one driver for each signal it assigns. All the loop iterations occur at the same `clk` event. `tmp` won't get updated until the next simulation cycle (after the loop is completed) and it's assignment is identical in all loop iterations, the expression `tmp + 1`.  The last loop iterated assignment would be the one that actually occurs and the value it assigns would be identical.

Using a loop statement isn't necessary when `counter` is state driven (state ≃ `tmp`).  The additional state represented by `i` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
entity mod10 is
    Port ( d : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      clr: in std_logic;
         clk : in std_logic);
end mod10;

architecture Behavioral of mod10 is

begin
  process(clk)                                    
    variable temp:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      begin
        if(clr='1') then temp:="0000";
          elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
              temp:=temp+1;
        if(temp="1010") then temp:="0000";
        end if;
        end if; 

      d<=temp;

 end process;  

end Behavioral;
```