# What is the iteration error in the loop?

Tags: loops, vhdl, fpga

```
loop
                if rising_edge (CLOCK) then   
                fcounter := fcounter+1;         
                end if;

                A<=fcounter(6);           --fa=fclock/2^6

                if rising_edge (A) then  
                counter_A:= counter_A+1;              
                end if;

                CIKIS<=A; --40 consecutive "1" consignment to DIN for STARTUP RESET 
                exit when counter_A=101000; --40
end loop;
```

ISE gives "ERROR:Xst:1312 - Loop has iterated 64 times. Use "set -loop_iteration_limit XX" to iterate more." What does that mean and what should i do to get rid of it?

Comment: Similar question with a nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430204/vhdl-program-to-count-upto-10-in-4-bit-up-counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbounded loops are not generally synthesizable outside of generating constants. The error is telling you that the loop has iterated beyond the preset limit that guards against infinite loops. Increasing the limit will not fix anything because what you have described doesn't map naturally to hardware with the current crop of synthesis tools.

You need to restructure your logic to inhibit that block of code with an enable that is deactivated when the counter reaches its terminal value rather than use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesizable constructs can't have compile time unbounded loops like this, they are only to be used in testbench code. The reason is that when they expand into hardware, something like this would require infinite resources (which you don't have). You seem to be trying to write this like a piece of software. When using a HDL, you need to be thinking of how it translates into hardware (assuming you plan to synthesize). Instead you might look at using a process where all activity happens inside an "if rising_edge(clock)", and use signals to explicitly use flip flops as opposed to variables which could go either way. It isn't entirely clear to me if you're trying to count when your fcounter rolls over 40 times (what you currently do) or when your fcounter exceeds 0111111 for 40 clock cycles, but you can use a signal indicating the state for either case instead of an exit statement, and an if/elsif statement on that signal to do something else when you don't want to have process counting. Sorry for the poor formatting, short on time.